# Why am I getting this Powershell hash literal was incomplete error?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to set a hashtable (dictionary) in PowerShell. When I try this line:

```
$users = @{abertram = 'Adam Bertram' raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo' zheng21 = 'Justin Zheng'}
```

I get the following error:

```
At line:1 char:38
+ $users = @{abertram = 'Adam Bertram' raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo' zhe ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'raquelcer' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:37
+ $users = @{abertram = 'Adam Bertram' raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo' zhe ...
+                                     ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... 'Adam Bertram' raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo' zheng21 = 'Justin Zheng'}
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Why do I get this and how do I set a hash table in PowerShell correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to separate Key/Value pairs on the same line with a semicolon `;`

```
$users = @{abertram = 'Adam Bertram'; raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo'; zheng21 = 'Justin Zheng'}
```

It may be preferable to use new lines though:

```
$users =
@{
    abertram = 'Adam Bertram'
    raquelcer = 'Raquel Cerillo'
    zheng21 = 'Justin Zheng'
}
```

Comment: Yup! That did it. Thanks!